# Nattable Cell with Multiple combination of images

Tags: nattable

We have a requirement to visualize a state of the cell.

Each cell represents user's DB CRUD access so each cell has four boolean flags for create, read, update and delete. To visualize, each cell should show four images with each image showing state of that flag.

We defined 8 labels (CREATE, NO_CREATE, READ, NO_READ etc) and adding these labels based on underlying model. So at any time, each cell will have 4 labels. We want to show 4 images in each cell with each image showing the state of corresponding flag.

Based on the research and from Dirk's suggestion, CellDecoratorPainter is the preferred approach. But each cell with a label is associated with one cell painter (in this case CellDecoratorPainter) so how do we use that to render combination of these images?

One approach I could think of is, instead of creating individual labels for READ, NO_READ etc., create 4x4x2 labels like READ_CREATE_UPDATE_DELETE, NO_READ_CREATE_UPDATE_DELETE and associate each of these labels with one cell painter decorator to paint series of images accordingly.

Not sure if that is the only possible approach. If any of you come across this type of situation, can you please share some thoughts?

PS: This is posted at Eclipse forums at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1782700/#msg_1782700

Comment: why downvote? This is a valid question, unless you explain otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested that we use custom image painter to achieve this as explained at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1782739/#msg_1782739.

Snippet of response is

> You could implement a custom ImagePainter that inspects the cell
> labels and draws images based on the labels in the label stack. Or
> stack CellPainterDecorators so that every decorator has an image as
> decoration that is only painted in case of the cell label, and has
> another decorator as base painter.
>
> But honestly, writing a custom ImagePainter that inspects the labels and draws the images on occurence of a label seems to be more
> intuitive.

We implemented CombinationImagePainter to achieve this and is available at https://gist.github.com/brsanthu/cd2f91da7777aa994e011f7acedd900a if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement wherein an image was to be displayed at the start and at the end. Almost the way you showed however we extended the AbstractTextPainter class and wrote the implementation according.